# Error when trying to import react-chartjs-2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron, chart.js

I am currently developing a software with Electron and for the graphic part, I wish to be able to display curves in real time with React and react-chartjs-2 except that when I imported the library for the curves, I had the following error :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.cjs 569:17
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (569:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     };
| class DatasetController {
>  static defaults = {};
|  static datasetElementType = null;
|  static dataElementType = null;
 @ ./node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist/index.js 2:0-185 85:31-38 162:4-11 168:54-68 169:52-65 170:56-71 171:62-80 172:64-83 173:58-74 174:52-65 175:60-77
 @ ./src/js/App.js
 @ ./src/js/index.js
```

Here is the code (webpack) :

Webpack.common.js :

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  target: 'electron-renderer',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [[
              '@babel/preset-env', {
                targets: {
                  esmodules: true
                }
              }],
              '@babel/preset-react']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: [/\.s[ac]ss$/i, /\.css$/i],
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'js'),
  },
};
```

I tried to install cjs loader with these command `npm i -D cjs-loader`:

But i had a new error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.cjs
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/cjs-loader/cjs-loader.js):
C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\cjs-loader\cjs-loader.js:23
import * as utils from './utils.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at new Script (node:vm:99:7)
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:242:18)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:186:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at loadLoader (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:18:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3)
    at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:446:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:981:14
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:409:6
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:155:13
    at AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:138:29
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingenieur komiflo\Sail Vision\Electron-React\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:346:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
 @ ./node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist/index.js 2:0-185 85:31-38 162:4-11 168:54-68 169:52-65 170:56-71 171:62-80 172:64-83 173:58-74 174:52-65 175:60-77
 @ ./src/js/App.js
 @ ./src/js/index.js
```

Comment: Chart.js is not written in Javascript but instead in Typescript. You have to install the TS loader for webpack.

`npm install --save-dev ts-loader`

then in your webpack.common.js add the TS loader in rules array.

Comment: I didn't know that it was a typescript library, i had the following the error when i tried the command `npm install --save-dev ts-loader` : `sailvision@1.0.0
Found: webpack@4.46.0
node_modules/webpack
  dev webpack@"^4.44.2" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from ts-loader@9.4.2
node_modules/ts-loader
  dev ts-loader@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.`

Comment: You can either update the webpack version to 5 or higher, or you can downgrade your tsloader to compatible with webpack

Comment: Yes i updated the webpack to version 5 and it worked now. But i had new error in the following question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110555/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-chartinstance-of-null?noredirect=1#comment132547067_75110555