# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chartInstance' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I tried to use the react-chartjs-2 library for the graphics part of my electron software. The problem is when I run via the npm start command, I get the following errors when I look in the console:

**First error** :

```
Uncaught Error: "arc" is not a registered element.
    at Registry._get (chart.js:5027)
    at Registry.getElement (chart.js:4974)
    at Chart.buildOrUpdateControllers (chart.js:5809)
    at Chart.update (chart.js:5843)
    at Chart.<anonymous> (chart.js:5602)
    at Chart._doResize (helpers.segment.js:601)
    at Chart._resize (chart.js:5691)
    at Chart.resize (chart.js:5662)
    at attached (chart.js:6233)
    at Chart.bindResponsiveEvents (chart.js:6245)
```

**Second error** :

```
react-dom.development.js:88 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

**Third error** :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chartInstance' of null
```

I can't figure out where my error is coming from?

Here are the code :

**App.js** :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useSyncExternalStore } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal/Modal'
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';
//JSON.parse(event.data)
//<Doughnut ref={chartReference} data={data} />

export default function App() {
  const chartReference=useRef(null);
  const [da,setDa]=useState({
    labels: ['Red','Green','Blue'],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [5,7,6],
            backgroundColor: ['red','green','blue'],
        },
    ],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      const chart = chartReference.current.chartInstance;
      setDa([
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
      ]);
      chart.update();
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
        <div>
            <div className="home">
                <div className="template-1" id="temp1">
                    <div class="panel-5">
                        <div class="panel-header">
                            <h1>Profil des sections</h1>
                            <i class='bx bx-cog modal-trigger-panel'></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="profil-container">
                                <Doughnut ref={chartReference} data={da} />
                            </div>
                            <div class="button-sec">
                                <input type="submit" value="Section 5" class="btn"/>
                                <input type="submit" value="Section 4" class="btn"/>
                                <input type="submit" value="Section 3" class="btn"/>
                                <input type="submit" value="Section 2" class="btn"/>
                                <input type="submit" value="Section 1" class="btn"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button-sail">
                                <input type="submit" value="Foresail" class="btn-hs modal-trigger-hs"/>
                                <input type="submit" value="Mainsail" class="btn-ms modal-trigger-ms"/>                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
  );
}
```

**EDIT** :

I added the following lines:

```
import {Chart,ArcElement} from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(ArcElement)
```

It displays the graph but I get the following error in the console as the graph is not reloaded:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'da' of undefined
    at App.js:35
```

Regards,

Comment: Please, edit your question to include relevant code only.

Comment: you initilaize your state with an object, then in your useEffect, you update your state with an array. So I assume `setDa` in your `useEffect` is not well formated

Comment: So i have tried these : `chart.da.datasets[0].data =` instead of `setDa` but i had just these error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chartInstance' of null at App.js:30`

Comment: I have edited my question with the new errors that i have.

Comment: @Feyto Have you got your solution?